# Postgresql cluster initialization

Tags: postgresql, installation

SQL distributes pre-initialized catalog cluster but for postgresql we need initialize cluster using initdb and a network service account. It fails in few cases and causing bit of misery!

Can initialize cluster ourselves and distribute pre-initialized cluster?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have more information about how it is failing? Do you see any error message?

Comment: well random stuff. postgre user needs to have access on root etc. 8 dot 3 issues. We do not want to change as customers do not like that. That's why I was thinking for distributing preinitialized cluster. Wanted to have some thoughts.

Comment: if you're talking about the debian / ubuntu functions like pg_cluster type commands, yes, they need to be root to be executed.

OTOH, initdb does not need to be run by root, so that if you are in the current directory of user joe, you can run initdb -D /home/joe/mydb to create a cluster.

Comment: nope in windows. random failures and postgres user needs full right throughout the folder chain

Answer (score 1):

The "cluster" (or data directory) depends on the operating system and the architecture. So a data directory that was initialized with initdb on a 32bit Linux will not work on a 64bit Windows.

But you don't need to do that. A service account is only necessary if you want to run PostgreSQL as a service.

You can easily use the ZIP distribution to install and start Postgres without the need for a full-fledge installation or a service account.

The steps to do so are:

1. Unzip the binaries
2. Run initdb pointing it to the directory where the database cluster should be created.
3. Run pg_ctl to start the server.

Note that the steps 2) and 3) must be run using the same user, otherwise the server will have no priviliges to write to the data directory.

These steps can easily be put into a batch file or shell script.

Comment: That's what is being done at present. We are windows based and postgres binaries are distributed with our installer. During installation the binaries are copied and initdb is used to initialize the cluster. Around 70% of times it works but 20-30% times it fails.

Comment: so thats why i was asking if the pre-initialized cluster can be distributed with our installer. As 30% failure is unacceptable and causing a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your question, but I think you are talking about the Windows installer for PostgreSQL. Right? What version, what installer, what about error messages, loggings, etc. ?

The installer can be found [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do#windows).

> **SQL** = database language, **SQL Server** =
>   Microsoft database product

Comment: it is postgres 8.4. we are not using postgres installer. we copy the binaries and initialize the cluster after copying binary into a folder.

Comment: Why don't you embed the installer into your own installer? That's what we did for our package (Java/Jboss/PostgreSQL) and it works like a charm.

Comment: You need to install MS installer 4.5 to have msi and we needed to customize few things in the postgress.